# How to change love2d code to suit corona sdk (both are in the lua language)

Tags: lua, coronasdk, love2d

I created a game using the love2d framework and now I want to transfer it to the corona sdk. Unfortunately, I'm receiving an error as corona doesn't support love functions. How to correct this? Thanks!

main.lua (basically the love.something functions are throwing error as shown at the bottom of this page)

```
-- load function to call menu.load() from menu.lua 
function love.load() 
    mode = require "menu"
    mode.load() 
end 
-- draw function for images
function love.draw()
    mode.draw()
end 
-- keypressed function to control user inputs
function love.keypressed(key, isrepeat) 
    mode.keypressed(key)
end
-- update function (delta time) to update variables/perform mathematical calculations.
function love.update(dt)
    mode.update(dt)
end
```

menu.lua

```
-- load variables/menu table
local menu = {} 
local selection; 
local bannerMenu;
local pointer; 
operSys = love.system.getOS() 

-- -- play function. If called by local options, require game.lua and then load the game.load function in game.lua.

local function play() 
    mode = require 'game'
    mode.load() 
end 

-- instructions function. If called by local options, require instructions.lua and then load the instructions page. 
local function instructions() 
    mode = require 'instructions'
    mode.load() 
end 

local function betatest() 
    mode = require 'betatesters'
    mode.load()
end

local function changelog() 
    mode = require 'changelog'
    mode.load()
end

local function sound()
    mode = require 'sound'
    mode.load() 
end
-- displays options that user can select from 
local options = { 
    {['text'] = 'Play', ['action'] = play},
    {['text'] = 'Instructions', ['action'] = instructions},
    {['text'] = 'Beta Testers', ['action'] = betatest},
    {['text'] = 'Changelog', ['action'] = changelog },
    {['text'] = 'Sound Options', ['action'] = sound},
    {['text'] = 'Exit Game', ['action'] = love.event.quit}

}
-- load function for menu. loads background image, banner, pointer.
function menu.load() 
    background = love.graphics.newImage(MENU_BG)
    bannerMenu = love.graphics.newImage(BANNER)
    selection = 1 
    pointer = love.graphics.newImage(POINTER)
    mode = menu 
    mac = love.graphics.newImage(MAC)
    windows = love.graphics.newImage(WINDOWS)
    linux = love.graphics.newImage(LINUX)
end 
--  returns mode variable. 
function menu.update() 
    return mode
end 
-- draw function for menu. draws background, banner, prints my personal accrediation, draws pointer.
function menu.draw()
    love.graphics.draw(background)
    love.graphics.draw(bannerMenu, 200, 10)
    love.graphics.printf("Your Operating System: "..tostring(love.system.getOS()),0, 560, love.graphics.getWidth(), 'center')
    love.graphics.printf("----- Created by Saksham Yadav ----- \n \n (Version 2.3)",0, 500,love.graphics.getWidth(), 'center')
    if operSys == "OS X" then 
        love.graphics.draw(mac, 530,510)
    end
    if operSys == "Windows" then 
        love.graphics.draw(windows,530,510)
    end
    if operSys == "Linux" then 
        love.graphics.draw(linux, 530,510)
    end
    for i=1,#options do 
        if i == selection then 
            love.graphics.draw(pointer, 300, 160 + i * 20)
        end 
        love.graphics.printf(options[i].text,-10,160 + i * 20, love.graphics.getWidth(), 'center') 
    end 
end 
-- keypressed function for menu. Controls user selection 
function menu.keypressed(key)
    if key == "up" then 
            selection = (selection - 2) % (#options) + 1 
    elseif key == "down" then 
            selection = (selection) % (#options) + 1 
    elseif key == "return" then 
            options[selection].action() 
    end 
end
-- returns menu table 
return menu
```

error

Corona Simulator Runtime error
Attempt to index global 'love' (a nil value)

File: main.lua
Line: 87
stack traceback:
    main.lua:87: in main chunk

Answer (score 2):

There is no magic answer here. You need to *port* the code over.

Lua is an [embeddable language](http://www.lua.org/about.html), and in these instances things like `love` are provided by the *host program*. You will need to replace the things that are provided by the `love2d` environment with things that are provided by the `corona` environment.

In your case, this is almost the entirety of the code shown.